# Draggable widget, how to delay appearance and replace coordinates with javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

So I created a script that when a widget is moved, the new coordinates are uploaded to a table. Data gets there but when I refresh the page, the widget reverts back to its original position. This is because I used `position: absolute;` in the page css section to display the icon initially before it was dragged.

So I thought that when the page is loaded, I could just delay the icon/widget from showing until php has the coordinates or no coordinates, in which case it would not alter the `position: absolute;`

`#icon` is initally set to `display: none;`

I tried a simple script through body onload

```
<body onload="position();">
<script>
document.getElementById("icon").style.display = "inline-block";
</script>
```

Actually I think I just figured it out, I set the default coordinates through php which I can change by checking the table if it was moved.

Comment: so delete the question? Or answer it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i understand really your problem,First set your widget display at none,and in your function position(),you have to request asynchronously the DB with **AJAX**(use jquery for example for that) or with **websockets**.Once you get data,show your widget in the right position.

A Basic ajax example:

```
function position()
{
    $.ajax({url: "your php file for getting data from db", success: function(result){
       // result will contain data,this can be xml,text,json...what you want
      // here you show your widget with the position result.
    }});
}
```

php file:

```
<?php 
//DB connexion,....  
$result = // get....
return $result;
?>
```

this is not a complete answer(ajax options,security....),it's just the concept.

Comment: This is the problem, the widget positions itself correctly, initially, the php precedes the html/css code so I imagine it is executed first? So by the time the html/css is processed, the variables should have been set.

Comment: I got it to work, my widget name wasn't matching ha. Thanks for your answer.